# Inserting data into MySQL database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm new to PHP and MySQL and I'm trying to insert data in to a database, which had worked fine until i attempted to use PDO's prepare method. It returns the catch error and i cannot figure out why - i'd also like to know whether it's best practice to use unnnamed placeholders or named placeholders?

The username and password variables are defined earlier in my code and catches data from the user using `$_POST`.

EDIT: getMessage() error displays `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null`

```
if (!empty($user) && (!empty($password)) ) {
    try {
        $results = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info (username, pass) VALUES (?,?)");
        $results->bindParam(1,$username);
        $results->bindParam(2,$password);
        $results->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Could not insert data in to the database";
    }
}
```

Comment: `echo $e->getMessage();` see what is the error.

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null

Comment: You are referencing `$user` and then referencing `$username`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different variable names. You're checking `$user` to make sure it's not `empty()` but then you tell bind `$username` to the first parameter. You'll just need to rename one of them to match the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
if (!empty($user) && (!empty($password)) ) {
try {
    $results = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info (username, pass) VALUES (?,?)");
    $results->bindParam(1,$user);
    $results->bindParam(2,$password);
    $results->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not insert data in to the database";
}
```

}

Please try yourself first to find the error.